# Android Test Sharding in on Multiple Devices

Tags: android, android-testing, sharding

"I am trying to run a set of Instrumentation Tests for the application that I have. I want to shard the test cases to 2 emulators that can save me some time. I am using the following command for that:"

```
 ANDROID_SERIAL=emulator-5554 gradle connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.numShards=2 -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.shardIndex=0

 ANDROID_SERIAL=emulator-5556 gradle connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.numShards=2 -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.shardIndex=1
```

Current result: Though the test is divided into 2 groups, both commands do not run parallelly.

Is there a way to run both the commands parallelly at the same time on both emulators?  Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

See the link [Shard Your Android Espresso Tests](https://medium.com/mesmerhq/shard-your-android-espresso-tests-for-faster-execution-in-parallel-e66f1b5061ae). I don't fully understand the bash commands that make this work but it does run in parallel.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./gradlew assembleAndroidTest
pids=
env ANDROID_SERIAL=emulator-5554 ./gradlew \
    connectedAndroidTest \
    -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.numShards=2 \
    -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.shardIndex=0 \
    -PtestReportsDir=build/testReports/shard0 \
    -PtestResultsDir=build/testResults/shard0 \
    &
pids+=" $!"
env ANDROID_SERIAL=emulator-5556 ./gradlew \
    connectedAndroidTest \
    -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.numShards=2 \
    -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.shardIndex=1 \
    -PtestReportsDir=build/testReports/shard1 \
    -PtestResultsDir=build/testResults/shard1 \
    &
pids+=" $!"
wait $pids || { echo "there were errors" >&2; exit 1; }
exit 0
```